# Неоднозначность перегруженной функции в C++

Tags: c++

В книге Шилдта наткнулся на вот такой пример неоднозначности перегруженной функции:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

char myfunc(unsigned char ch);
char myfunc(char ch);

int main()
{
　cout << myfunc('c'); // Здесь вызывается myfunc(char).
　cout << myfunc(88) << " "; // Вносится неоднозначность.
　return 0;
}

char myfunc(unsigned char ch)
{
　return ch-1;
}

char myfunc(char ch)
{
　return ch+1;
}
```

Не могу понять, почему не возникает неоднозначности когда аргументов является 'c'? Ведь для него подходят обе функции.

Answer (score 5):

Литерал `'c'` имеет тип `char`, а не `unsigned char`.

Типы `char`, `signed char`, `unsigned char` - это три разных типа:

```
std::is_same<char, unsigned char>::value //false
std::is_same<char, signed char>::value //false
```

Соответственно для вызова с аргументом типа `char` никаких преобразований не нужно и будет выбрана

```
char myfunc(char ch);
```

Что касается неоднозначности с аргументом типа `int`, то неясно, приводить аргумент к типу `char` или типу `unsigned char`.

Answer (score 5):

`'c'` - это символьная константа, соответствующая типу `char`, а для ее приведения к типу `unsigned char` необходимо преобразование. А `88` - это целочисленная константа соответствующая типу `int`, для ее приведения как к типу `char`, так и к типу `unsinged char` требуется преобразование.

Answer (score 4):

Вопрос тут не в том, "подходят" или "не подходят" обе функции, а в том, есть ли среди всех подходящих функций одна единственная *однозначно лучшая* чем остальные, согласно правилам overload resolution.

В случае `myfunc('c')` такая функция есть - это `char myfunc(char ch)`, ибо тип ее параметра `char`в точности совпадает с типом предоставленного аргумента `'с'`. В этом случае неоднозначности нет.

В случае `myfunc(88)` обе имеющиеся функции *одинаково* хороши (или одинаково "плохи"), ибо обе требуют преобразования типа аргумента и в обоих случаях преобразования фактически одинаковы (`int -> char` и `int -> unsiged char`). Поэтому в этом случае возникает неоднозначность.